# Swiftの { }内の処理の流れが分かりません。

Tags: swift

下のコードの
`signIn(withEmail:link:)`メソッドの`{}`内の処理の流れがよく分かりません。
`self.hideSpinner{}`は必ず実行されるのしょうか？
このような構文は何と呼ばれるものですか？

```
if let email = self.emailField.text {
    showSpinner {
        // [START signin_emaillink]
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, link: self.link) { (user, error) in
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            self.hideSpinner {
                if let error = error {
                    self.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                }
                self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
        // [END signin_emaillink]
    }
} else {
    self.showMessagePrompt("Email can't be empty")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

メソッド呼び出しの後ろについている `{ ... }` は クロージャ (Closure) と呼ばれるものです。
`signIn(withEmail:link:)` だけではなく、 `showSpinner` や　`hideSpinner` にくっついている `{ ... }` もクロージャです。

クロージャは関数のようなものですが、クロージャ自体を変数に入れたり、他のメソッドや関数に渡したり、戻り値として返したりすることができます。

簡単な例を上げると以下のようになります

```
// "ABC"をプリントするクロージャ
let c1 = {
    print("ABC")
}
c1() // ABC と表示される

// 与えられた整数を2倍にするクロージャ
let c2 = {
    (a:Int) -> Int in
    return a * 2
}
c2(2) // 4が返される

// クロージャを引数に受け取る関数
// 与えられたクロージャを二回呼び出す
func f1(closure: ()->Void) {
    closure()
    closure()
}

// "ABC"が二回プリントされる
f1(closure: c1)

// 関数の最後の引数がクロージャの場合、関数の後ろに { } をくっつけて書くことができる
f1 {
    print("Yeah!")
}
```

これを踏まえると

> self.hideSpinner{}は必ず実行されるのしょうか？

は **`signIn(withEmail:link:)` の実装や処理結果による**

が回答になります。
メソッド名からは、サインインが成功したら `user`、失敗したら `error` に値を入れて、クロージャが呼び出されるのではないかと期待しますが、本当にそうかは分かりません。
(実装やAPI仕様を確認したり、実際に実行して試してみたりすれば分かるでしょう)

**追記**

forestさんの過去の質問から、おそらくSwiftよりJavaScriptの方が詳しいのかと思います。
なので元のプログラムをJavaScript風に翻訳してみましょう。以下のようになります。

```
this.showSpinner(function() {
    // [START signin_emaillink]
    Auth.auth().signInWithEmail(email, this.link, function(user, error){
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        this.hideSpinner( function() {
            if (error) {
                this.showMessagePrompt(error.localizedDescription);
                return;
            }
            this.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true);
        });
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    });
    // [END signin_emaillink]
});
```

つまり、Swiftのクロージャ `{ ... }` はJavaScriptの無名functionと同じでものです。
無名functionはメソッドの引数として、それぞれ `showSpinner`, `hideSpinner`, `signIn` という別のメソッドに渡されていることも分かると思います。渡されたfunctionをどう扱うかはそれぞれのメソッドによります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。self.hideSpinner{  }の{  }は引数ということですね。ということは、{  }内はとりあえず必ず実行されるという理解でよいでしょうか。実際に試してみるのが一番よさそうですが。

Comment: いえ、`hideSpinner`に引数として渡されたクロージャが実行されるかは `hideSpinner` の実装次第です。おそらくスピナーが非表示になった後に実行されるじゃないかと思いますが私には断言できません。試してみてください。

Comment: `hideSpinner`の評価（戻り値）がtrueの時に実行されると考えてよろしいでしょうか？（それとまず`hideSpinner`という関数が別にあるということですかね）

Comment: そうではありません。`hideSpinner`の実装次第です。`hideSpinner`がまだ作成途中でメソッドの中身が空っぽだったりするならもちろん実行されません。`hideSpinner`のソースが確認できないなら、APIドキュメント等を確認してください。それすらないなら実際に試してみるしかありません。

Comment: `hideSpinner`は仮に設定されたもので、実装はないと思われます。（別の質問として書きました https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/56773/仮に設定された識別子の形式がわかりません）

Answer (score 1):

> `signIn(withEmail:link:)`メソッドの`{}`内の処理の流れがよく分かりません。

`{}`は、クロージャ（Closure）です。まったく実用面で意味のないクロージャですが、わかりやすさ優先で例を出すと、

```
let plus = { (a: Int, b: Int) -> Int in
    return a + b
}
```

`(a: Int, b: Int)`が引数部分、`-> Int`が返り値を表し、`in`以下がクロージャの実装部分です。すなわち、関数と同じ構造になっており、ほぼ関数と同じ働きをします。関数でなくクロージャを使う利点は、例のように、クロージャを変数に代入できることです。上のコードに続いて、

```
let c = plus(a: 4, b: 3) // c = 7
```

と書いて、クロージャを実行できます。まんま関数ですね。クロージャと関数の違いは、主にその永続性にあります。関数（独立関数）は、グローバルで、プログラムと同じ寿命を持ち、クラスのメンバーである関数、すなわちメソッドは、インスタンスと同じ寿命になります。対して、クロージャは、一般の値型変数と同じく、コードブロック（`{`から`}`まで）がその寿命になります。
クロージャは、ほかの言語で「ラムダ式」、「無名関数」などと呼ばれていますので、Swiftから離れて、少しネットで調べてみるといいでしょう。

---

クロージャは変数に代入できますから、関数の引数になります。クロージャを引数にとる関数の例を示します。

```
func hoge(a: Int, b: Int, operation: (Int, Int) -> Int) -> Int {
    return operation(a, b)
}
```

クロージャを代入した変数にも型があり、それは`(Int, Int) -> Int`のような表記になります。

```
let m = hoge(a: 3, b: 4, operation: plus) // m = 7
```

クロージャ型の引数は、直接クロージャの実装を記述することができます。

```
let n = hoge(a: 8, b: 3, operation: { (a, b) -> Int in
    return a - b
})
// n = 5
```

ここまではよろしいでしょうか？
クロージャを引数にとる関数に対して、Swiftは特別な構文を認めています。クロージャ型の引数が最後尾にあるという条件で、クロージャを`()`の外に出すことができます。上のコードは、このように書き換えできます。

```
let n = hoge(a: 8, b: 3) { (a, b) -> Int in
    return a - b
}
```

クロージャの実装が長くなると、関数の最後、`})`が何のことなのか、すぐに判断できにくくなります。そういう判断のしにくさを緩和する意図だと思われます。

---

> このような構文は何と呼ばれるものですか？

ここまでくると、この疑問に答えを出すことができますね。すなわち、クロージャを引数にとるメソッドです。
あともうすこしです。（ここで全て疑問が解けているなら、これ以上読んでいただかなくてもけっこうです）
ではつぎの二つのケースを考えてみましょう。ひとつは、関数の引数がクロージャ型一つだけ取るケース。もうひとつは、引数も返り値もないクロージャというケース。この二つのケースを満たすサンプルはこうなります。

```
func fuga(doThis: () -> ()) {
    doThis()
}
```

引数も返り値もないクロージャの型は、`() -> Void`ないし`() -> ()`と書きます。後者が推奨されているようです。
この関数を実行するには、こう書きます。

```
fuga(doThis: { () -> () in
    print("Hello")
})
// 出力 Hello
```

（関数の書き方と同じく、返り値のないクロージャは、`return`行を書きません）
これを省略した構文で書くと、まずクロージャ型の引数は`()`の外に出され、かつ`()`は記述不用となります。そして、クロージャの引数と返り値の型は省略され、`in`も不用となります。

```
fuga {
    print("Hello")
}
```

これで、`self.hideSpinner{}`の謎が解決しました。お疲れ様でした。